Yoneda lemma in a functor semicategory
I've read that the Yoneda lemma does not hold in general for semicategories (i.e., 'categories' possibly lacking identity morphisms)[1]. However, I'm wondering about a related situation, where there is an underlying symmetric monoidal closed category $C$, and then a 'functor semicategory' $F$ constructed over it, where the objects in $F$ are endofunctors $V : C \rightarrow C$, and the morphisms are natural transformations between them, but where for any functor $V\in \text{Ob}(F)$, the identity natural transformation $\text{id}_V$at $V$ might not exist. Is there much known about this kind of situation? Should I still expect the isomorphism $F(c) \cong \text{Nat}(y^c, F)$ given by the Yoneda lemma (where $c \in C$ and $y^c$ denotes the endofunctor represented at $c$) to hold?
[1] https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma#the_yoneda_lemma_in_semicategories

Why wouldn't the identity natural transformation exist?

@QiaochuYuan, I'm imagining a setting where the natural transformations that are included as morphisms in the category F are of a restricted class that's generated by some rule, and this rule happens not to produce identity natural transformations. Is there some reason they must exist?

Why not just include them? Do you have a specific example in mind?
